# type [...number[], string] remains the same after last element was popped

Tags: typescript

I have an array typed as a tuple with multiple numbers and a string at the end. After popping the last element, I know that the array now contains numbers only, but TypeScript doesn't. How do I help TypeScript understand this?

```
const mixedArr: [...number[], string] = [1, 2, 3, 'Hello']
const str = mixedArr.pop() as string
mixedArr.forEach(item => {
  item * 2 // causes problems, bc item is seen as string | number
})
```

Comment: Avoid mutation if you want to infer all types. TS does not track mutation

Comment: Furthermore, `tuple` data structure should be immutable by the default.

Comment: Without something like [ms/TS#40316](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40316) in place, the only way to deal with this is to explicitly abstain from mutating methods. It's unfortunate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare a new local with the correct type:

```
const numbers = mixedArr as number[];
numbers.forEach(item => item * 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a variable is declared, you will not be able to change it's type. If you wanted you could set it to type any using `any[]`, or declaring a new variable doing something like `let numArr = mixedArr as number[];`

Answer (score 0):

The variable is of type `string | number`, which you can also workaround with `switch` statement.

```
const mixedArr: [...number[], string] = [1, 2, 3, 'Hello']
const str = mixedArr.pop() as string
mixedArr.forEach(item => {
  switch(item) {
      case item as number: item * 2;
  }
})
```